# The dual problem of polyhedron projection problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

If we define a polyhedron
$$
D:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\mid Bx=d,x \geq 0\},
$$
where $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $d \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, the projection problem associates to $D$ is
$$
\min \ \frac{1}{2}\|x-c\|^{2}, \ \text{subject to } Bx=d,x \geq 0.
$$
The equivalent problem is
$$
\min \ \frac{1}{2}\|x-c\|^{2}+\delta_{C}(x), \ \text{subject to } Bx=d,
$$
where $C$ is defined by $C:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\mid x \geq 0\}$ and \delta_{C}(x) is the indicator function, which is defined as if $x \in C$ equals to 0 and $+\infty$ otherwise.

The Lagrangian function is
$$
l(x,y):= \frac{1}{2}\|x-c\|^{2}+\delta_{C}(x)-\left<y,Bx-d\right>.
$$
Therefore, the dual problem is
$$
\max_{y}\min_{x}\frac{1}{2}\|x-c\|^{2}+\delta_{C}(x)-\left<y,Bx-d\right>. 
$$
Consider the minimization problem, a equivalent reformulation is
$$
\min_{x} \ \frac{1}{2}\|x-c-B^{\top}y\|^{2}+\delta_{C}(x)+\left<y,d\right>-\left<B^{\top}y,c\right>-\frac{1}{2}\|B^{\top}y\|^{2}
$$
Then, we can conclude that $x=\Pi_{C}(c+B^{\top}y)$ with \Pi_{C} a projection onto $C$.
Thus, the dual problm is
$$
\max_{y} \frac{1}{2}\|\Pi_{C}(c+B^{\top}y)\|^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\|c\|^{2}-\left<\Pi_{C}(c+B^{\top}y),c+B^{\top}y\right>+\left<d,y\right>.
$$
However, the answer is
$$
\max_{y} -\frac{1}{2}\|\Pi_{C}(c+B^{\top}y)\|^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\|c\|^{2}+\left<d,y\right>.
$$
I do not know where I make some mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both expressions coincide.

Hint:
Try to simplify
$$
\langle \Pi_C(z), z \rangle.
$$

Comment: Thanks, when $C$ is a closed convex cone, we can use the fact that $\left<\Pi_{C}(z), z\right>=\left<\Pi_{C}(z), \Pi_{C}(z)\right>$

Comment: @Kim: Yes, I am glad that it helped!